# Design timeseries schema for cassandra

Tags: cassandra

My application want to display photos uploaded for a day in descending manner.

I looked at weather station example for cassandra where i get timeseries data for particular station. In my case i want to track all photos present in system. I have designed schema like below:

```
create table if not exists photos(
photo_id uuid,
category text,
owner uuid,
date text,
created timestamp,
primary key((date),created)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC);
```

Here `date` is `MM/DD/YYYY` string representation of `created` date.

The problem here is when I do select I want latest photo based on `created` date. I get back rows in random order (well they are ordered in desc order if they have same date). I want to fetch rows for latest date when I do select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem here is when I do select I want latest photo based on created date. I get back rows in random order

Actually, they are in order by the hashed value of your partition key (`date`).  Cassandra can only maintain clustering order *within* a partition key.  This is why rows with the same `created` are sorted "if they have the same date."

> I want to fetch rows for latest date when I do select.

You *can* do that.  All you need to do is specify a date when you do it.

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE date='03/28/2015';
```

By restricting your partition key, your rows will be returned in their defined clustering order.  From your application or reporting level, generating the current date shouldn't be too hard to do.

Also, not to self-promote, but earlier this month Planet Cassandra posted an article that I wrote on this subject (largely based on questions I have answered on this site): [We Shall Have Order!](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/)  Give that a read and it should help you with these types of problems.

Comment: If i need to get all photos for specific month, can i modify this schema for that purpose (at present date is partitioning key so its less likely to work, still want to confirm) or  should i create new table ?

Comment: @turbo Yes, I would go with an additional table called `photosByMonth`, with `PRIMARY KEY((month),created,photoid)` (`photoid` added just to ensure uniqueness).

Answer (score 0):

**Please try " Order by  " in select operation. It will bring the data as per date**

> Below example shows the value of photos based-on created date in ascending order.

```
cqlsh:temp> SELECT * FROM photos WHERE created in (1427524795784,1427524795899) and date = 'march-28'  ORDER BY created ASC ;


 date     | created                  | category | owner                                | photo_id
----------+--------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------

 march-28 | 2015-03-28 10:39:55+0400 |   nature | 007aa9b5-c86b-4805-a65d-6019d1ba820b | 007aa9b5-c86b-4805-a65d-6019d1ba820b
 march-28 | 2015-03-28 10:39:55+0400 |   nature | 007aa9b5-c86b-4805-a65d-6019d1ba820b | 007aa9b5-c86b-4805-a65d-6019d1ba820b
```

Comment: Cassandra already returns rows in their clustering order.  All `ORDER BY` really lets you do is change the sort direction (ASCending vs. DESCending).  Also, your example might be more convincing if the rows were actually different.